# Error logging in c++

Tags: c++

I implemented a very simple (error) logger class. It looks like this:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

extern const char* LOG_DEFAULT_TEXT =  "<LOG>\n\n";

class Log
{
public:
    Log() : _logs(0), _log(LOG_DEFAULT_TEXT) {};

    void add(const char *str, bool nl=true);
    void clear();

    const char* get() const { return _log.c_str(); }
    int getNumLogs() const { return _logs; }


private:
    std::string _log;
    int _logs;
};
```

Now my question is, say I have this Main class, that contains all the other objects that my program may contain, and also this Log class.
Obviously I would want these "other objects" in my Main class to be able to use the Log object in Main, so the easy solution would be to pass pointers to every class' constructor so that it could use the Log object.

I'm talking about something like this:

```
//Main.h
...

#include "Log.h"

class Main() {
public:
  ...

private:
  Log _log;
  ImportantObject1(&_log); //pass a pointer to _log
  ImportantObject2(&_log); //..same
};
```

This solution seems too clumsy, so I'm asking if there are different approaches for what I want to accomplish, which is error logging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's one of the rare cases a singleton makes sense:

```
class Log
{
public:

    void add(const char *str, bool nl=true);
    void clear();

    const char* get() const { return _log.c_str(); }
    int getNumLogs() const { return _logs; }

    static Log& instance() {
         static Log theInstance;
         return theInstance;
    }
private:
    Log() : _logs(0), _log(LOG_DEFAULT_TEXT) {};

    std::string _log;
    int _logs;
};
```

This way you can use it elsewhere just accessing

```
 Log::instance().add("Blah Blah",true);
```

Comment: And if a more flexible approach is needed, that would be the [Service Locator](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/service-locator.html) pattern.

Comment: @Quentin That's sounds a bit over engineered for such simple use case as logging.

Comment: You're returning a local variable as a reference, it won't work well ;)

Comment: I actually never really got the idea behind singletons, now I do. I've always been told horrors about them :P

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Mentioning it just in case :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Service locator patterns are very common for loggers.  It's really only a few lines more than a singleton.  Lots of loggers go even further and use dependency injection too because it allows to mock the logger and change-out the logger implementation.  See log4j, log4net, log4cxx

Comment: @MobyDisk I know well, these logging frameworks use that pattern. Anyhow OPs post claims a _simple_ logger class, if I'd thought they'll need something more sophisticated, I would have recommend using one of these frameworks, instead of rolling your own (unless a good reasoning was given).

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to address the requirement...

**Use functions in a suitable `namespace` instead of a singleton.**

Log.h:

```
namespace Log
{
   void add(const char *str, bool nl=true);
   void clear();

   const char* get();
   int getNumLogs();
}
```

Log.cpp:

```
namespace detail
{
   // This is almost same as the class from OP's post.
   struct LogImpl
   {
      LogImpl(std::string const& log) : _logs(0), _log(log) {};

      void add(const char *str, bool nl=true);
      void clear();

      const char* get() const { return _log.c_str(); }
      int getNumLogs() const { return _logs; }


      std::string _log;
      int _logs;
   };
}

namespace Log
{
   // This mimics the singleton implementation...
   // Create only one instance of LogImpl.

   static detail::LogImpl impl("<LOG>\n\n");

   void add(const char *str, bool nl)
   {
      impl.add(str, nl);
   }
   void clear()
   {
      impl.clear();
   }

   const char* get()
   {
      return impl.get();
   }
   int getNumLogs()
   {
      return impl.getNumLogs();
   }
}

namespace Log
{

   void add(const char *str, bool nl=true);
   void clear();

   const char* get();
   int getNumLogs();
}
```

**Using functions in a `namespace` vs using a singleton**

To support use of functions in a namespace requires bit more code.

However, it simplifies calling code.

Calling code can use

```
Log::add(...);
```

instead of

```
Log::instance()->add(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another common pattern inherited from C would be a global object. Globals are generally frowned upon because they are the symptom of bad design. But it makes sense for a logger to be a global.

That means that the header for your class should contain :

```
extern Log log;
```

and the cpp

```
#include <log.h>
...
Log log;    // unique definition for the global Log
```

Then in any module using the log :

```
#include <log.h>
...
log.add(...);
```

The caveat here that there will be static initialization of `Log log`. And C++ is not always very nice with order of static initialization : *... Otherwise, the initialization of a variable is indeterminately sequenced with respect to the initialization of
a variable defined in a different translation unit.*. The only foolproof way is to ensure that :

- Log construction does not depend on any other statically initialized variable needing a constructor phase in another translation unit - it includes `std::string` but hopefully not `const char *`
- the global variable is used once before any multithreading starts

If in doubt, use the singleton pattern suggested by πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: One point must be said while using globals: If the order of construction of global objects is not well defined, you can run into trouble. Maybe another global objects is created and try to log but the logger isn't available, the system crashes without a log ;) But having singletons end up in dependency trees and so on. No pattern is perfect. If you know what you do, global objects are cheap and fast. But if you don't, they are the start of a nightmare!